# What is the right schedule value of a dag to skip 2nd & 26th of the month?

Tags: python-3.x, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer, airflow-2.x

#### CONTEXT

Airflow version: `2.6.3`

Composer version: `2.5.1`

I need to configure a DAG to skip scheduled runs for specific days (2nd & 26th specifically) of the month.

#### WHAT I'VE DONE

To test this, I created a new DAG to skip the current date (as of 2023-12-20) + 2nd + 26th + Tuesdays to Saturdays.

1. Created a new DAG with a `schedule` cron value of `0 0 1,3-19,21-25,27-31 * 2-6`

   - upon appearing on the Airflow UI, this DAG automatically ran as soon as it was created. I was expecting that the DAG shouldn't have ran because of the cron value that I set above.

#### WHAT TO DO

I'm confused how does Airflow recognize and correctly skips specific days of the month using the cron expression values of the `schedule` parameter in the DAG object.

1. Is my assumption right that I could immediately test a DAG to skip the current date by passing it a value of `0 0 1,3-19,21-25,27-31 * 2-6`?
2. What should be the cron expression value of a DAG to skip the 2nd & 26th days of each month with the following added conditions:

   - should run at 00:00 in every month (`0 0 x * x`)
   - should run every Tuesdays to Saturdays in every month (`x x x * 2-6`)

I'd really appreciate any help and insights regarding this matter. Feel free to let me know if I need to add more information and edit my post. Thank you!